# Vector move semantic c++11

Tags: c++11, vector, move

I have been searching for a while but I couldn't find clear explanation for my doubts. 
Mainly:

```
struct foo
{
    foo(int n=0) : m_n(n) {}
    int m_n;
};

  std::vector<foo> vec;
  vec.push_back(100);
  vec.push_back(55);
  vec.push_back(6);

  std::cout << vec.data() << std::endl; //0x1aca010
  std::cout << vec.capacity() << std::endl; //4
  vec.push_back(6);
  vec.push_back(6);
  std::cout << vec.data() << std::endl; //0x1aca050  *
  std::cout << vec.capacity(); //8
```

*As I understand a vector is an dynamic array which contains data in one continuous block of memory. When we resize it and there is out of space for more elements, new block of memory is being allocated and all elements are copied to that one. Does it work the same with respect to the move semantic in c++11? It's not a list so pointers can't be just "swaped".

Comment: There is no move operation here, in C++ 11 it is supposed to work by the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think pointers can't just be "swapped"? Let me show you a possible implementation >o<

```
template <typename T>
class vector
{
private:
    T *mem;
    // ...

public:
    // ...
    vector(vector &&rhs)
        : vector() // delegate constructor
    {
        rhs.swap(*this);
    }
    vector &operator =(vector &&rhs)
    {
        rhs.swap(*this);

        rhs.clear();
        rhs.shrink_to_fit();

        return *this;
    }
    void swap(vector &obj)
    {
        using std::swap;
        swap(mem, obj.mem);
        // ...
    }
    // ...
};
```

However, if you want to use a different allocator from an original vector (i.e. to use the sixth constructor of [this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector)), you should allocate new memory and copy data into it, not just swap pointers.

Comment: I do understand that in some cases pointers can be just "swaped", that's the point of move, but does it work in this case?

Comment: @AdamAdamowicz What is `this case`? Aren't you saying about move semantics?

Comment: "In this case" I meant resizing the vector. I just wanna know does a vector's implementation copies all elements from previous block to the new allocated block or not.

Comment: @AdamAdamowicz When resizing, of course vector allocate new memory and copy data.